# How does material design style icons based on text node children

Tags: material-design, native-web-component

Based on the code snippet below ([and found here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/tree/master/packages/icon#basic)), the material library is styling the component based on the text content of **mwc-icon**. After looking at the source code for **mwc-icon** found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/blob/master/packages/icon/src/mwc-icon.ts), there doesn't seem to be any javascript logic doing the styling directly. Somehow this seems to be happening in the css or in the font definition itself.

*How is the icon being applied/rendered in place of the text?*

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons&display=block" rel="stylesheet">

<mwc-icon>shopping_cart</mwc-icon>

<script type="module">
  import '@material/mwc-icon';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your question is that the font-family property set in the file.
You have imported the Material Icons font and used it. There is where the icon name you enter is defined. Instead of character definitions icon names are defined and mapped to the corresponding svg or png images.refer [here](https://css-tricks.com/ligature-icons/)

Comment: Can a font family convert multiple characters into a single glyph? And how does that work?

Comment: I am not good at that. But after google did it. It seems so we can define multiple characters but without spaces.

Comment: Thank you! you pointed me in the right direction to research it more